# How to print array of dictionary value in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

Hello i getting api response from backend like following.

here i need to retrive the "userId" from following [Any] type.

```
[{
  "userId" : "5e633967c04aff49e5e22c5b",
  "onlineStatus" : 1
}]
```

i tried with the following code but in my case it gives error.

```
let data = Array(chatdataArray) as? [[String:Any]]
print(data)
```

Comment: Try using json decoding, google “Swift Codable” for instance

Answer (score 4):

First convert Array`[Any]` to array of dictionary `[[String: Any]]`, using `guard let` or `if let`.

```
guard let arrChatData = chatdataArray as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

print("User Id :: ", arrChatData[0]["userId"])
```

**Or**

Use **`Model`** for API responses using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper) for map data.

**Usage:**

Create models.

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

//MARK: - ChatDetails
struct ChatDetails: Mappable {

    var chatDataArray: [ChatDataArray]?

    init?(map: Map) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        self.chatdataArray <- map["chatdataArray"]
    }
}

//MARK: - ChatDataArray
struct ChatDataArray: Mappable {

    var onlineStatus: Int?
    var userId: String?

    init?(map: Map) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        self.onlineStatus <- map["onlineStatus"]
        self.userId <- map["userId"]
    }
}
```

After setUp of `Models` map API response.

```
if let responseDict = response as? [String: Any], responseDict.keys.count > 0 {
    if let chatDetails = Mapper<ChatDetails>().map(JSON: responseDict) {

        var arrChatList = chatDetails.chatdataArray
        print("User ID :: ", arrChatList[0].userId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Model:NSObject,Codable{
    var userId: String?
    var onlineStatus: Int?
}

do{

    let object = [["userId":"123"],["userId":"456"]]

    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: [])
    let array = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<Model>.self, from: jsonData)

    let model = array[0]
    let userId = model.userId

    print(array)
    print(model)
    print(userId)

}catch{
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```swift
import Foundation

extension Data {
    var prettyPrintedJSONString: NSString? { /// NSString gives us a nice sanitized debugDescription
        guard let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: []),
              let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: [.prettyPrinted]),
              let prettyPrintedString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else { return nil }

        return prettyPrintedString
    }
}


let str = "[{\"userId\" : \"5e633967c04aff49e5e22c5b\", \"onlineStatus\" : 1 }]".data(using: .utf8)!.prettyPrintedJSONString!
debugPrint(str)
```

Comment: No reason to use NSString when you have a native swift String class

Answer (score 0):

First I initalize it as Array of dictionary, then I fetched the desired item.

```
if let data = chatdataArray as? [[String: Any]]{
      for item in data{
       if let userId = item["userId"] as? String{
           print(userId)
      }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thanks! explained. and It works fine, Dont know who downvoted my answer and for what reason he/she did.

Comment: I think the reason of the downvote was that even though your answer seems to be correct, it lacked the necessary didactic element of explanation. I tend to only downvote very serious issues with questions or answers, so I didn't downvote your answer, but now it is worthy of upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood OP criteria correctly this looks like a nice case for using Swift higher order function approach.

```
let dic: [Any] = [["userId": "5e633967c04aff49e5e22c5b",
                    "onlineStatus": 1],
                  ["userId": "aaaa",
                    "onlineStatus": 0]]
let userIdValues = dic.compactMap{ ($0 as? [String: Any])?["userId"] }
print(userIdValues)
```

yielding

```
["5e633967c04aff49e5e22c5b", "aaaa"]
```

The `compactMap` will filter out nil entries if the `Any` element will not cast to `[String: Any]` during the `as?`